# How to set Column freeze in Grid?

Tags: html, wpf, xaml, grid, freeze

How can I set Column Freeze inside Grid in XAML? I know that DataGrid have FrozenColumnCount, but I must to use Grid (DataGrid is not an option). I had idea that scroll viewer don't effect first (i.e. my "frozen" column), but I dont know how to do that. Some ideas? Please help :-)

Comment: `must to use Grid (DataGrid is not an option)` - What are you trying to do? you're probably doing it wrong. `Grid` is intended to be used as a layout control, and nothing else. Post your current code and XAML and a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the proper way to do it in WPF.

Answer (score 1):

As a `Grid` is just a means of providing layout (i.e it isn't something that directly displays data in the way a `DataGrid` goes) you will have to roll-your-own version of frozen columns. You should be able to do this easily by placing a `ScrollViewer` (or layout control of choice) within the section you want to scroll. Then place your content within the `ScrollViewer` (like another `Grid`, say)

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```